# File chooser in Android WebView not working

Tags: android, asp.net, telerik, filechooser

I have implemented a file chooser in an Android WebView and I'm at the point of onActivityResult being called, right after selectiong a file (e.g. an image or a PDF).

This is how I open the file chooser:

```
    private void openFileChooserImplForAndroid5(ValueCallback<Uri[]> uploadMsg) {

        mUploadMessageForAndroid5 = uploadMsg;
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);

        String [] mimeTypes = {"image/*", "application/pdf"};
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("*/*");
        contentSelectionIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes);

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Select a document");
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_FOR_ANDROID_5);
    } // similar code is managing non-Android5
```

Then this is the onActivityResult method being invoked (comments in method signature contain the actual parameters):

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode /*2*/, int resultCode /*-1*/, Intent intent) {
    if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE) {
        if (null == mUploadMessage)
            return;
        Uri result = intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK ? null : intent.getData();
        mUploadMessage.onReceiveValue(result);
        mUploadMessage = null;

    } else if (requestCode == FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE_FOR_ANDROID_5) {
        if (null == mUploadMessageForAndroid5)
            return;
        Uri result;

        if (intent == null || resultCode != Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            result = null;
        } else {
            result = intent.getData(); 
            /*After this instruction, result contains a URI$HierarchicalUri with value content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/document%3A1000000036*/
        }

        if (result != null) {
            mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{result});
        } else {
            mUploadMessageForAndroid5.onReceiveValue(new Uri[]{});
        }
        mUploadMessageForAndroid5 = null;
    }
}
```

After this code, I have no idea where the selected file content is.
The webview is an aspx page like this

```
                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGridDI" runat="server" AllowPaging="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="RadGridDI_SelectedIndexChanged"
                        AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None">
                            <MasterTableView DataKeyNames="Id,DocuId,Filename" ShowHeader="false">
                                <Columns>
                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Filename" HeaderText="Header text" />
                                    <telerik:GridButtonColumn CommandName="Select" Text="View" UniqueName="column" ButtonType="PushButton"/>
                                </Columns>
                            </MasterTableView>
                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

How can I end up having the selected file to be processed?

Comment: intent getData() is the uri that points to the choosen file. Open an input stream for that uri and read

Comment: @blackapps thank you, but how can I "attach" that file to the file selector? The onReceiveValue method requires a URI, not a stream.

Comment: I do not get what you ask. If you selected a file then why would you continue with attach that file to a selecter? What would you select further?

Comment: `The onReceiveValue method requires a URI, not a stream.` Well your result variable is an Uri. So what is the problem? You are already doing so.

Comment: @blackapps The problem is that the RadGrid you can see in the last code snippet is not  seeing the file located at the fetched URI (i.e. what URI in the result variable). It's like something else is missing in my code.